# Internal Display Shows Up Only After Logout Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, display

*****Update 3:**

I just re-installed Ubuntu 20.04 and the default kernal (5.13.0-39-generic) is working fine with the "NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-510 (proprietary)".

---

*****Update 2:**

I just did a software update on Ubuntu 20.04 and there's black screen on my built-in monitor again, like installing the wrong nvidia driver I experienced before.

**Solution:**

1. Open up 'Software & Updates'
2. Go to 'Additional Drivers'
3. Choose nvidia-driver-510 (proprietary, tested).

---

*****Update 1:**

I did **steps 1 and 3 listed below** on a clean Ubuntu 18.04/20.04 and the issue (show up only after logout) didn't appear anymore on both Ubuntu versions.

Note that the linux kernel is specifically **5.11.14** because I tried some older and newer versions and all of them failed.

---

**Main problem:**

Every time I reboot and enter Ubuntu 18.04 (I set autimatically login), my internal monitor (165 Hz) keeps black screen (completely black) while the external monitor (60 Hz) via HDMI works well. I feel the internal monitor is working at that moment from moving my cursor to that monitor.

I also notice the display in this situation (account is locked and display is off because of screen saver) is weird: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntQXc.jpg)

After logging out once, the internal monitor works well (it shows up at the moment of logging out).

I've checked the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMs1P.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUowM.png)

The values in the above two pictures are the same in having the black screen or not.

I can use Ctrl+Alt+Del to logout when I only have the internal monitor / using it as the primary monitor.

However, I want to solve the problem but I have no idea where the problem is. Please help~~~

---

**Long story:**

I got a new laptop, Alienware m15 R5, with AMD Ryzen 7 5800H and NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060, 6 GB, GDDR6, and I got the problem of installing Nvidia driver for the graphic card.

After a long research of setting up the Nvidia driver, I realised the essential steps I did to get the driver works:

1. install kernel 5.11.14
2. copy all green_sardine* files from https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/amdgpu to /lib/firmware/
3. Disable "hybrid graphics / advanced optimus" in BIOS
4. Switch from gdm3 to lightdm display manager

Comment: Hey! Unrelated, but I'm thinking about getting the M15r5 to use as a Linux workstation. Have you got everything working okay? Why are you using Ubuntu 18.04 instead of 20.04 (or later)? How loud are the fans? In the BIOS, is there an "iGPU ONLY" mode? If not, can you completely power down the Nvidia GPU so it doesn't draw any power?

Comment: I've got everything working now, on both Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04. I used 18.04 in last semester because one of the courses required for ROS melodic. // The fans are fine. They're loud only when I run heavy stuff. Normally they're quiet 90% of the time. // I didn't see iGPU related stuff. // I think it's possible to disable nvidia GPU. Some of my classmates did, so I'm quite sure it's possible.